# Generically obtaining a pointer to a multi-dimensional C++ array's first element

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types, multidimensional-array

If I want to set a pointer to the first element of a multi-dimensional C++ array, I can easily do it:

```
double arr[2][3][4];
double *p;
p = &arr[0][0][0];
```

How can I do this for an array of arbitrary rank? A function receiving a reference to a multi-dimensional array can be written as follows:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
void receive(T (&a)[N]) {}
```

The C++11 `std::remove_all_extents` class template can be used to obtain an array's (deepest) element type. This could help construct the return type for a modified version of `receive` using `typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type *`. But how should the returned *value* be created?

The following solution uses `reinterpret_cast`. This will presumably be executed efficiently, but I dislike `reinterpret_cast`'s circumvention of the type system.

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type *
to_ptr1(T (&a)[N])  { return reinterpret_cast<
                               typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type *
                             >(&a); }
```

Alternatively, the following solution uses recursion, and while the type system remains strong, the recursion may introduce additional instructions.

```
template <typename T> T *to_ptr2(T &a)  { return &a; }

template <typename T, unsigned N>
typename std::remove_all_extents<T[N]>::type *
to_ptr2(T(&a)[N])  { return to_ptr2(*(&a[0])); }
```

How can I obtain the address of a multi-dimensional array's first element generically? Is there a strongly typed solution with zero overhead?

Comment: What's not strongly typed in the solution with `reinterpret_cast`? It's IMO fine and I don't think it'll get any better than that.

Comment: I'm out of practice with the metaprogramming wizardry, but I'm quite sure the solution would involve [`std::rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank).

Comment: There is no issue with the `reinterpret_cast` version - arrays are guaranteed to not have initial padding.  I wonder if `remove_all_extents` isn't implemented via a recursive template anyway.

Comment: `remove_all_extents` will be implemented using recursion. Here the result of the calculation is a type - this must be done at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>    

template<size_t Rank>
struct deref_n
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T& ptr) -> decltype(deref_n<Rank-1>()(*ptr))
    {
        return deref_n<Rank-1>()(*ptr);
    }
};

template<>
struct deref_n<0>
{
    template<typename T>
    T& operator()(T& val)
    {
        return val;
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto first_element(T& val) -> decltype(deref_n<std::rank<T>::value>()(val))
{
    return deref_n<std::rank<T>::value>()(val);
}


int main()
{
    int x[10][20][30] = {};
    first_element(x) = 777;             // this gives me a reference to x[0][0][0]
    std::cout << x[0][0][0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Alas this seems to follow a very similar recursive scheme to `to_ptr2` from the original question.

Comment: The template recursion may be resolved at compile-time ... try checking your compiler's generated assembly if this concerns you

Comment: Hi Matt. I'm only concerned about the best solution. If a recursive strategy always means that I should check the assembly, this would weigh against it.

Comment: You don't need to check the assembly. Template instantiation is always resolved at compile time.

Comment: Template instantiation is always resolved at compile time; however the function calls to the instantiated objects, may be performed at runtime. For example, using `deref_n` or `to_ptr2`, with a 3D array, will *potentially* result in 3 function calls at runtime.